# How to refer to another model using object_id in a http statement when posting? (mongo db)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, rest

I'm using a mongodb to create the REST API for an express app with node.js.

I created three different schemes that are somehow related to each other e.g. a book was written by an author and published by a publisher.
Here is the **scheme** for the book.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    }, 
    author: {
        type: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'},

    },
    publisher: {
        type: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Publisher'},

    },
    isbn: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema)
```

Each of those schemes has an id, but I'm using the default id that is generated when posting an object.

Here is a part of the **route-file**.

```
//Creating one Book
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const book = new Book({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author.findById,
        publisher: req.body.publisher.findById,
        isbn: req.body.isbn
    })

    try {
        const newBook = await book.save()
        res.status(201).json(newBook)
    } catch {
        res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
    }
})
```

I am using a **.rest-file for testing**.

```
###
POST http://localhost:3000/books
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "title" : "test",
    "author" : "615c429dfe31a3863b6ebc8e", //object_id of an author in the db
    "publisher" : "615f3daf330081bcd5010861", //object_id of a publisher in the db
    "isbn" : "1234"
}
```

When I run this statement it will just create an object containing the object_id, a title and an isbn. The author and the publisher are left out. I did not set author and publisher as required in the scheme because it would throw an error (failed to cast string to object_id). I already tried that.

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid this casting error?
I already googled and watched tutorials, but i did not find anything, yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference between [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) and [MongoDB native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) will automatically convert(Typecast) into Type defined in schema.

Your schema looks fine, you just need to change it like

```
//Creating one Book
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const book = new Book({
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
        publisher: req.body.publisher,
        isbn: req.body.isbn
    })

    try {
        const newBook = await book.save()
        res.status(201).json(newBook)
    } catch {
        res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea!
 I left out the "findById" as you suggested, but unfortunately it doesnt work either.

When posting a book it now just have its id, its title and its isbn. The author and publisher are still ignored. I tried to change the model so that the author and publisher are required but that throws an error in the console saying the following

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `author.required`. See "bit.ly/mongoose-schematypes" for a list of valid schema types.